# Grails Hide ID parameter in URL

Tags: grails

Hi this is a sample url `mailBox/messageDetailsInbox/79` As you can see there is and ID parameter after last slash  "79".   "mailbox" is my controller and "messageDetailsInbox" is my action. I want to hide ID parameter in url. I want customize  url like this `mailBox/messageDetailsInbox`

This is my code

```
<g:link action="messageDetailsInbox"   id="${i.id}"> MyLink </g:link>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, if you need to pass data (e.g, your ID) to your controller/action and you don't want to do it via URL token or query parameters (i.e, HTTP GET method)

```
//GET method
http://server/controller/action/79        //token
http://server/controller/action?id=79     //query param
```

then you need to do a form POST. But unless you're sending lots of data or sensitive data, it's usually preferable to use the GET method because your URLs will be more bookmark-able.

Answer (score 1):

So, just don't add this ID to the link:

```
<g:link action="messageDetailsInbox"> MyLink </g:link>
```

If you still want to pass Id, but don't want to have in URL, you can pass it as a parameter:

```
<g:link action="messageDetailsInbox" params="${[id: i.id]}"> MyLink </g:link>
```

Comment: so how can i post id ? but i need id to retreive data by id

Comment: I can't understand - do you need to pass ID or not?

Comment: I tried your second solution, but the parameter still in URL of browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but:

1. If you don't have anything unique in URI to identify an object (**id**, **hash** or something else), then you can't just insert this url in browser and get this object. So, you can hide ID by hashing it to string like **b4eb2a176dc4baa110038a8a7f3c3562** and use it instead of id (but you have to save it to the database for quick search).
2. Or, for redirects you can save id of the current object in **flash** or in  **session**:

> session.current_id = 1234

or

> flash.current_id = 1234

And then do something like

> def msg = YouDomain.get(flash.current_id)

Answer (score 0):

Define a new url in `UrlsMapping.groovy` file in `config` folder

```
"mailBox/messageDetailsInbox"(controller: "controllerName", action: "messageDetailsInbox")
```

then pass the parameters in post. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 
   `<g:form controller="SomeController" action="SomeAction" method="POST">
      <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${your?.id}"/>
      <input type="submit" class="text-button" value="submit"/>
   </g:form>`
2. and in same .gsp add following css in head section
   `<style type="text/css">
       .text-button 
       { 
           background-color: Transparent;

           text-decoration: underline;

           color: blue;
           cursor: pointer; 
           border:0
       }

    </style>`